# Fit qtree into a A4 page

Tags: qtree

I have a pretty complicated qtree.

```
\Tree [.expr while 
             [.expr not 
                    [.expr 
                    ( 
                    [.expr 
                    [.ID a ] <-  [.expr [.ID z ] <- [.expr 0 ] ] ] ) ] ].expr 
             loop 
             [.expr [.ID y ] 
                    <- 
                    [.expr [.expr [.expr [.ID  z ] ] 
                                  + 
                                  [.expr [.expr [.Integer 2 ] ] 
                                         * 
                                         [.expr [.ID x ] ] ] ] + [.expr [.Integer 1 ] ] ] ] 
             pool ].expr
```

[image: output]

How shall I make it fit into a A4 page? I have been trying `!\qsetw{}` for hours and failed.

Comment: You could put the tree in a separate document and simple embed this in your main document as PDF. An alternativ could be to use GraphViz.

Comment: Use `resizebox` from `array` package
`\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
the content
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possibility via `resizebox` from [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package:

[image: output]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.expr while 
             [.expr not 
                    [.expr 
                    ( 
                    [.expr 
                    [.ID a ] <-  [.expr [.ID z ] <- [.expr 0 ] ] ] ) ] ].expr 
             loop 
             [.expr [.ID y ] 
                    <- 
                    [.expr [.expr [.expr [.ID  z ] ] 
                                  + 
                                  [.expr [.expr [.Integer 2 ] ] 
                                         * 
                                         [.expr [.ID x ] ] ] ] + [.expr [.Integer 1 ] ] ] ] 
             pool ].expr
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

If landscape is an option, add `lanscape` to the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) options:

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

You can change to [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) which uses a similar syntax and optimize space between tree elements.

Your tree with `forest` default style looks like

[image]

Of course `forest` provide instructions to make it wider or align certain elements with other ones, etc.

The code used to draw previous figure was:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[expr [while] 
      [expr [not] 
            [expr [(] 
            [expr [ID [a]] 
                  [<-]  
                  [expr [ID [z]] 
                        [<-] 
                        [expr [0]]]]
                  [)]]] 
       [loop] 
       [expr [ID [y]] 
             [<-] 
             [expr [expr [expr [ID [z]]] 
                        [+] 
                               [expr [expr [Integer [2]]] 
                                     [*] 
                                     [expr [ID [x]]]] 
                         [+] 
                         [expr [Integer [1]]]]]] 
       [pool]
       ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed one of the strong points of `qtree` is that it can easily be changed to `forest` when needed.